# PHPMailer best solution for looping through emails

Tags: php, email, sendmail, phpmailer

I am trying to build a recall system in which users are sent reminder emails based on specified criteria. At the moment I would probably be sending 10-15 reminders at a time each week but it's possible that this may escalate to hundreds each week in the future. I've decided to use PHPMailer class to handle mail sending but I am very new to PHPMailer and so i'm not sure if the solution I have come up with will give the best performance or if my code can be improved. Also I am storing the date the email has been sent once it has been sent successfully.

This is what I have come up with:

```
<?php
//I have left out the database connection details for obvious reasons

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patients_test WHERE recall <> 0 AND DATE_ADD(`last_seen`, INTERVAL recall DAY) < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 21 DAY)");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //Create new mail object
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    ///Mail settings
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'host.co.uk';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'myusername';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

    $mail->From = 'myusername';
    $mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
    $mail->addReplyTo('replytoadd', 'Information');

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Reminder email';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    //Recipient info
    $ref = $row['identifier'];
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $surname = $row['surname'];
    $email = $row['email'];


    $mail->addAddress($email, $first_name." ".$surname);     // Add a recipient
    if(!$mail->send())
    {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Reminder sent to '.$first_name.' '.$surname.' successfully<br/>';

        mysql_query("UPDATE patients_test SET last_reminder= CURDATE() WHERE identifier='$ref'");//Update database to show that email has been sent
        $mail->clearAllRecipients();
    }
}

?>
```

Also the reason why I chose not to use PHPs default **mail()** function is because I am worried that my emails will be blocked as spam and I read somewhere that using something like PHPMailer can reduce the chances of this happening. Does anyone have any advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance
Rich

Comment: Take a look to the mail's headers
[php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Look at the [PHPMailer example code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) for a much more efficient way to send to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill the mail's headers can reduce this issue. The mail server have some rules which define if the mail is a spam or not. Moreover, sending mails through a loop may cause a blocking depending on how it is configured.

Comment: Thanks Niels. I'll take the headers into account. Do you know of an alternative to running the mail sending through a loop?

Comment: I'm not sure, but either you handle your mail server and you can manage it's options, either you respect the minimum delay between two sending (You have to know it, or reduce the loop speed). 
Else I think it's possible to generate proxys on the fly but it's more difficult and not recommanded at all.
However if your mails had been received in spam directory, it's not due to the loop. By against if your mail sending had been blocked, it's probably the loop. Add headers had solved your issue ? Sorry for my english

Comment: Hi Niels, thanks your help. As of yet the emails haven't been placed in the spam directory but I'm just trying to take measures to prevent it from happening once the system I'm developing requires more bulky mail sends. Going from your advice I will definitely take care to make sure all of the headers are present.